# Countdown till midnight in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple question, that is giving me some problems. I am trying to configure a countdown timer, so that it would show the remaining hours, seconds and minutes. I got some great code online, but I have to modify it, so that it is dependant of the current time and not the time when somebody visits the site. 
The code I use is this: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/

I have been working on the *script.js* and corrected this:

```
$(function(){

    var note = $('#note'),
        ts = new Date(2012, 0, 0,0,0),
        newYear = true;

    if((new Date()) > ts){
        // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
        // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
        var uraJe = new Date();
        var ura = 24 - uraJe.getHours();
        var minute = 60 - uraJe.getMinutes();
        var sekunde = 60 - uraJe.getSeconds();
        ts = (new Date()).getTime() + ura*60*60*1000;
        newYear = false;
    }

    $('#countdown').countdown({
        timestamp   : ts,
        callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

            var message = "";

            note.html(message);
        }
    });

});
```

When I run it, it does show the hours correctly, but the minutes are not.

How can I correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>New year is at `new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)`, not at `new Date(2012, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. Notice the 1 vs 0 and the extra 0. I don't know if that fixes your remaining minutes problem though..</strike>

**edit**

So if you want `ts` to be midnight of the current/next day, you can use `setHours()` on a `date` object of the current day.

```
var today = new Date(); 
today.setHours(23, 59 ,59, 1000);
```

This will result in today being the beginning of the next day, because of `1000ms`. If you want the date to stay on the current day you can use `999ms`

Comment: That actually has nothing to do with what i am working on, that condition is not being met anyway, and is thus redundant. It is the old code i used from the given link...

Comment: Perhaps it is better to remove redundant code. Makes it a lot easier to see what you are trying to achieve. Make a JsFiddle reproducing your problem

Comment: I know that the problem is in here:'        var uraJe = new Date();
        var ura = 24 - uraJe.getHours();
        var minute = 60 - uraJe.getMinutes();
        var sekunde = 60 - uraJe.getSeconds();
        ts = (new Date()).getTime() + ura*60*60*1000;'

Comment: So you want `ts` to be midnight of the current/next day.. you can use `setHours` on a date object of the current day. `var today = new Date(); today.setHours(23, 59 ,59, 1000);` This will result in today being the beginning of the next day, (because of 1000, use 999 to stay on the current day)